# How to find records BETWEEN with FTS5 and MATCH?

Tags: sqlite, fts5

How can I search for a (price) range in a SQLite3 database with a FTS5 table?

This is a strongly simplified example table:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE fruits USING fts5 (id, name, price);
INSERT INTO fruits (id,name,price) VALUES (1, 'Apple with A', 5);
INSERT INTO fruits (id,name,price) VALUES (2, 'Pineapple with B', 10);
INSERT INTO fruits (id,name,price) VALUES (3, 'Cucumber with C', 20);
INSERT INTO fruits (id,name,price) VALUES (4, 'Melon with D', 25);
INSERT INTO fruits (id,name,price) VALUES (5, 'Kiwi with E', 30);
INSERT INTO fruits (id,name,price) VALUES (6, 'Cucumber with F', 35);
INSERT INTO fruits (id,name,price) VALUES (7, 'Cucumber with G', 40);
```

The following command returns the expected two records 3 and 7 for Cucumber:

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE fruits MATCH 'name:Cucumber AND (price:20 OR price:40)';
```

How can I search for the Cucumbers in the price range 20 to 40 (to include record 6 in the above example)? If I try it with

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE fruits MATCH 'name:Cucumber AND (price: BETWEEN 20 AND 40)';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE fruits MATCH 'name:Cucumber AND (price: BETWEEN 19 AND 41)';
```

I get no result (or error message) at all. Is it not possible to use MATCH and BETWEEN in one query?

---

And in addition:
Why does the command

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE fruits MATCH 'name:C';
```

return only one record (id: 3) and not 3, 6 and 7, assuming the C in 'Cucumber' will be found too, not only the C in 'with C'?

Answer (score 7):

FTS tables store everything as text; it does not make sense to have the `id` and `price` columns in an FTS table.

The only efficient queries on an FTS table are searches for words (and lookups by the internal `docid`).

You should treat the FTS table not as a table but as an *index*. Keep the other data in a 'real' table, and do any other queries on that table:

```
SELECT *
FROM fruits
WHERE id IN (SELECT docid
             FROM fruits_fts
             WHERE fruits_fts MATCH 'Cucumber')
  AND price BETWEEN 20 AND 40;
```

To search for words beginning with `C`, you must use a [prefix search](http://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#full_text_query_syntax).

Comment: is there also a way to add the range filter to the score anyhow? So rank is only determined by the MATCH clause here?!

Comment: @nhaberl To ask a question, use the ["Ask Question" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).